# Getting error as : Error: Client.createUser parameter 'opts mspid' is required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to use the IBM blockchain. I have created the setup on IBM blockchain, now I am trying to register the user though node-SDK from on the IBM blockchain, however, I am getting an issue when I am trying to register the app-admin to IBM blockchain.

Please help me to find out the issue or let me know where I am doing wrong.

Connection file.

```
{
    "name": "mychannel",
    "description": "Network on IBP v2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "org1msp"
    },
    "organizations": {
        "org1msp": {
            "mspid": "org1msp",
            "peers": [
                "n77513f-peer0org1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "n77513f-org1ca.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7054"
            ]
        },
        "org2MSP": {
            "mspid": "org2MSP",
            "peers": [
                "n77513f-peer0org2.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "n77513f-ordererorg1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-ordererorg1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        },
        "n77513f-ordererorg2.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-ordererorg2.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        },
        "n77513f-ordererorg3.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-ordererorg3.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        },
        "n77513f-ordererorg4.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-ordererorg4.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        },
        "n77513f-ordererorg5.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-ordererorg5.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7050",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "n77513f-peer0org1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-peer0org1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "n77513f-peer0org1.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud"
            }
        },
        "n77513f-peer0org2.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051": {
            "url": "grpcs://n77513f-peer0org2.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "n77513f-peer0org1retail.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "n77513f-org1ca.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7054": {
            "url": "https://n77513f-org1ca.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7054",
            "caName": "ca",
            "tlsCACerts": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my config file.

```
{
  "connection_file": "connection.json",
  "appAdmin": "admin",
  "appAdminSecret": "org1capw",
  "orgMSPIiD": "dFarmMSP",
  "caName": "n77513f-org1ca.mycluster-108893-93897c9faea121bae05cda32f6fe4dd1-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud:7054",
  "channelname": "mychannle",
  "username":" ",
  "role":" ",
  "chaincodeName":"dfarmsm",
  "gatewayDiscovery": { "enabled": true, "asLocalhost": false }

}
```

node.js code for register the admin

```
'use strict';

const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const {
    FileSystemWallet,
    Gateway,
    X509WalletMixin
} = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();


const configPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'Config.json');
const configJSON = fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8');
const config1 = JSON.parse(configJSON);

var connection_file = config1.connection_file;
var appAdmin = config1.appAdmin;
var gatewayDiscovery = config1.gatewayDiscovery;
var appAdminSecret = config1.appAdminSecret;
var orgMSPID = config1.orgMSPID;
var caName = config1.caName;

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'connection.json');

const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

let response = {};

class FabricClientRegister {
    constructor() {
         console.log("called constructer");
    }
    async RegisterAdmin() {
        try {


            const setAsyncTimeout = (cb, timeout = 0) => new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    cb();
                    resolve();
                }, timeout);
            });


            // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
            const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities[caName].url;
            const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);

            // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
            const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
            const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
            console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
            // logger.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

            // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
            const adminExists = await wallet.exists(appAdmin);
            // console.log('here is admin exit')
            // console.log('AdminExits', adminExists);
            if (adminExists) {
                response.data = null;
                response.httpstatus = 400;
                response.message = `An identity for the admin user ${appAdmin} already exists in the wallet`
                // console.log('res', response)
                return response;
            }

            // Enroll the admin user and import the new identity into the wallet.
            const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
                enrollmentID: appAdmin,
                enrollmentSecret: appAdminSecret
            });

            const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(orgMSPID, enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
            wallet.import(appAdmin, identity);
            // logger.log('msg: Successfully enrolled admin user ' + appAdmin + ' and imported it into the wallet');
            console.log('msg: Successfully enrolled admin user ' + appAdmin + ' and imported it into the wallet');
            response.data = identity;
            response.httpstatus = 200;
            response.message = "admin enrolled successfully"
            return response;


        } catch (error) {
            response.error = error;
            response.httpstatus = 500;
            response.message = "Failed to enroll admin due to above error";
            return response;
        }
    };
```

Let me know if anything I missing. and thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the mspid you are passing in to `createIdentity` is blank. In your config you define the msp id as

```
"orgMSPIiD": "dFarmMSP",
```

whereas in your code you try to retrieve it as

```
var orgMSPID = config1.orgMSPID;
```

(Note the difference between `iD` vs `ID`)

so basically the value of `orgMSPID` will be `undefined`.

However it would be useful for the createIdentity to report an error as no mspid is given so I would suggest you raise a jira for the fabric-sdk-node project (FABN) at https://jira.hyperledger.org and suggest that createIdentity should check for a undefined mspid on the input parameters